Hide warnings and/or errors when importing Keras
My script imports the following Keras modules:
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.utils import to_categorical

and every time the same warnings/errors are shown:
2024-07-20 10:51:48.653282: I external/local_xla/xla/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:32] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2024-07-20 10:51:48.657088: I external/local_xla/xla/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:32] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2024-07-20 10:51:48.670352: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:485] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2024-07-20 10:51:48.710318: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:8454] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2024-07-20 10:51:48.722894: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1452] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2024-07-20 10:51:50.112114: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT


I've tried some suggestions I found like:
from keras.config import disable_interactive_logging
disable_interactive_logging()

or
import tensorflow as tf
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)

but neither worked. Can these messages be hidden somehow?

try using the warnings library, and you can make sure that the TensorFlow log messages are configured for the error level, I think it could help you
Example code for your case:
import warnings
import tensorflow as tf
import os

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=FutureWarning)
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=UserWarning)

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')

os.environ['XLA_FLAGS'] = '--xla_hlo_profile'


Unfortunately this does not work

This would probably work if you import tf after calling methods from warnings and os module.
